# Publishing Wowza RTMP stream to JW player

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, wowza

Using wowza streaming engine at present for streaming from my local network outwards, although the settings are quite ambiguous and many Google searches have come out fruitless.

I'm able to see my video under the "test streams" section, so we know the RTMP encoding from my machine to Wowza SE woks well..
My issue is publishing outbound, we need the final result to appear on our website. I've signed up for JW player and input settings with the external facing IP address, but cannot see where I would publish the stream outbound with the Wowza streaming engine.

I have a lot of experience streaming via a CDN using wirecast / FMLE (FMLE being used in this instance) but not much experience with the Wowza streaming engine.
Can anyone give advice how to vonfigure the Wowza streaming engine for outbound streams, and how to pick these up with JW player on a webpage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? The first Google results point you to the documentation.  Have you read the documentation, it offers you all the information you need: [How to set up live streaming using an RTMP-based encoder](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36), [How to use JW Player with Wowza Streaming Engine](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?484-How-to-use-JW-Player-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine)